# Number of section retraction pairs in category of sets

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

Suppose in category of $finite$ $Sets$, $A$ and $B$ are two sets, such that $|A| \ge |B|$ (Where $|i|$ represents cardinality of set $i$). I wanted to enumerate $(r,s)$ pairs (Section-Retraction pairs) such that

$$r:A \rightarrow B, s: B \rightarrow A$$
and 
$$r \circ s=1_B$$.

Suppose this specific $(r, s)$ pairs are in a set $RS$, I found that for a given $A, B$,

$$|RS|=(|B|)^{|A|-|B|} \frac{|A|!}{(|A|-|B|)!}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You first count the number of allowable sections $s$, which must be injective from $r \circ s = 1$.  This is a permutation count $P(|A|, |B|)$ as you've correctly identified.  Once the section is fixed, you must count how to retract to it.  Well, the points in the image of $s$ are nailed down by the section, so you need only count the rest.  Since you're in the category of sets with no structure, you have complete freedom here.  This gives $|B|^{|A|-|B|}$ as you've concluded.  So, the final answer is the product you've stated.